# Downvote should not be negative

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

As we know, fake points matter to a lot of people. Including me. I like fake points because that's all I have. I am underpaid in real life job, I am doing bad as indie developer, I got bills to pay, my dog hates me, my cat can't be bothered. So, the only thing I have in this life is FAKE POINTS! SO's fake point makes me happy. So, I want to request to change the sign of Votes instead of -2 or -4, change it to other signs. Squiggly lines is good "~" so it is like worm. I prefer worms than negative signs. At least when my question is downvoted, I get few worms instead of negative marks.

Thanks.!
Edit: Add image to illustrate my award winning idea:
[Worm Count example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo63H.jpg)

Comment: "-" doesn't inherently mean "negative." We've arbitrarily defined it as such. If it's replaced with "~" it'll just be the same situation.

Comment: [this](https://output.jsbin.com/veyuvexaku) is live footage of a crawling worm. As you can see it looks like a minus half the time so replacing it with a squiggly just creates the opposite problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know how to word this any more politely: if "the only thing you have in life is fake Internet points", then you need to go and find a hobby. Play video games, go for a walk, watch some Netflix. There's more to life than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are you sure it's the sign that you are bothered by? Not the red color?

Comment: You could make a user script for that. And be nice with the dog.

Comment: Electrons are negative. Just pretend you're being given electrons.

Comment: "Your post is rotten, here's a worm."

Comment: Upvoting for the lulz. Thanks for making my day.

Comment: @TheWanderer But it is negative. My fake points is deducted when someone downvote me. I'd prefer my fake points remain as it is. And downvotes would be a separate number like Badges. Worm is just suggestion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What were the results of the A/B experiment where negative question scores were clamped to 0?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393907/what-were-the-results-of-the-a-b-experiment-where-negative-question-scores-were)

Answer (score 10):

Changing how the downvotes are presented doesn't change the fact that fake points will be deducted, indirectly as a consequence of making a negative contribution to the site. Replace all minus signs with squiggly worms, and you'll still have all the rejects complaining about how "SO is hostile and unwelcoming with its worms". Downvotes will still be perceived as something negative. And worms will be given a bad name in tech for no justifiable reason.

Worse, having the worms presented alongside the badges would make yet another opportunity for discrimination based on the user: "the answer's poster has too many worms, so it is likely wrong"; or "I won't be bothered to address questions from users with too many worms". Both behaviours would be incentivised by the UI, but are actually unacceptable conduct.

This, of course, invalidates the original premise of your proposal. Can't have a yin without a yang. Consider seeking to improve your life first, which in turn will help you see and embrace the purpose of downvotes on the site.