# Should vote count be hidden for new questions?

Tags: discussion, voting

I noticed that when a question gets downvoted, it *sometimes* tends to attract 2 types of voters: the ones that go with the rest and downvote it too, and the ones that upvote just because of pity, to balance the vote count.

Should SO hide new questions vote count for a predefined time, so new voters don't get influenced by the current vote count?

I'm not saying that all downvotes or upvotes are caused by this, but it would be nice some kind of functionality test with control groups to see the real effect of knowing the voting count if it really has a correlation or it's just my impression.

Comment: This was tried in the past (within the past 2 years), but we never got actual data from the result, only testimonies from people who worked on it but no longer had access to the data. TLDR, it didn't work out. it caused a lot of confusion, and not a whole lot of positive results

Comment: @KevinB oh, didn't know about that, good to know. Just out of curiosity, do you have any links to the posts about it?

Comment: Found the one that talked about the results: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393907/what-were-the-results-of-the-a-b-experiment-where-negative-question-scores-were?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Check the "Linked" section for other posts related to it, including the announcement

Comment: also, whoops, that was almost 3 years ago

Answer (score -29):

For discussion, I would suggest hiding user name also, because of biased voting neglecting actually posted content of questions/answers (and many seem biased, that new questions from low reputation users are low quality content, what should be disagreed with on that rigour.)
Even today I recognized a question/answer not available for dynamic plotting details for a special use case for dynamic usability pattern, what took quite some time finding a solution. No information available on Stack Overflow knowledge database.

Even a question/answer that was not perfect would have been more helpful if voting would consider content and allowed that question/answer, so hiding score and/or user name to biased followers might help towards community support for question/answers that are rare and maybe not understood (instantly) by many.

Comment: Actually... new users are often treated with upvotes more readily than not new users... when their post isn't low quality. (don't however confuse new users with low rep users)

Comment: Might be an interesting test to put the bias myth to bed once and for all

Comment: even a question/answer that was not perfect would have been more helpful if voting would consider content and allowed that question/answer, so hiding 'score/user name' to biased followers might help towards community support for question/answers that are rare and maybe not understood (instantly) by many

Comment: @charlietfl i'm pretty sure people have tested that several times throughout the years, that when they participate with a new account using all the knowledge they have about the system in terms of creating quality content, they had an overwhelmingly positive reception. but... I have no idea how to search for it

Comment: Not to mention... the system currently does the opposite of this, and has been doing it for a long time now. New users get a badge under their user badge that marks them as a "New Contributor." If being a new user generally causes people to react negatively to them, surely they would have removed that by now.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to imply with "*a question/answer not available for dynamic plotting details for a special use case for dynamic usability pattern*". Either no one has asked about it, or it's not reasonably scoped for SO.

Comment: Most described the more obvious usage patterns, but no mentioning of iteration through data file for plotting multiple (dynamically defined) objects. The more obvious/common usage examples are the other way round with multiple input data into one plotting object (what was not our interest). Just one example for content limitations from my point of view.

Comment: The only bias that exists here is the one you cultivate yourself. If you consistently post incorrect, low quality, or offensive content, people may start to recognize your name. I'm not convinced that's a bad thing.