# Change downvotes with negative points to something else

Tags: feature-request, downvotes

We should promote positivity in the site. Thus usage of *negative* values for downvotes should be changed.

My proposal:

Avoid showing any number at all. Since it does not matter whether it is downvoted 10 times or 1000 times, just add the word "Downvoted".

Thank you for reading.

---

Henry Ecker pointed out the magnitude of the uselessness of the answer is important. So my idea is to remove the points-based system altogether. There are no more + or - points, and just use progress bar as indicator.

0 votes

▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒

10 votes

▒▒▒▒ █▒▒▒

-10 votes:

▒▒▒█ ▒▒▒▒

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how this proposal helps future visitors, most of whom would land here via web searches. When would it be useful for them to see some answers with a score like 2 or 10, while another shows a nonsense number?

Comment: @VLAZ Nonsense answer will have "Downvoted" word. The -ve point is still in database for sorting purpose, just hide the number is all.

Comment: It seems there's already been an [experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390178/why-can-i-no-longer-see-that-a-post-has-a-negative-score) to this effect, the [results of the experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393907/what-were-the-results-of-the-a-b-experiment-where-negative-question-scores-were) seem to suggest this is not a good approach.

Comment: "it does not matter whether it is downvoted 10 times or 1000 times" does it also not matter whether a post is upvotes 10 or 1000 times? Why isn't this proposal symmetric?

Comment: The vast majority of (undeleted) negatively scored posts are score -1 (by a __large__ margin). ([SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1622753) / [Bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VrnF.png)). I think obscuring a -1 with something like "DOWNVOTED" changes the (perceived) meaning from "One person did not find this post useful" to "This post is not useful" and that means, in the majority of circumstances, this proposal gives a worse impression of the post than just showing the score.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks for sharing that but it is not the same as what I am suggesting. I am saying that the downvote value is STORED in db, just that it is NOT DISPLAYED. So downvoted answers will still be recognizable from those with 0 votes.

Comment: @VLAZ i think you don't understand. My idea is that the Downvote value is stored in DB, just that it is not displayed, instead just show the word "DownVoted".

Comment: @GeneCode I understand *that*. I don't understand this proposal considers negative score any different from positive score and is not symmetric in both directions.

Comment: @VLAZ it does not need to be symmetric, no?

Comment: @HenryEcker good point. Then a way to indicate the weight of the downvote shall be formulated. My idea is to put progress bar.

Comment: *Why* does it not need to be symmetric? What makes positive scores different from negative scores? Why should a score of 10 or 1000 be relevant to show but a score of -10 or -1000 not be?

Comment: @VLAZ just the same way car speedometer has a +ve speed and shows 0 when reversing.

Comment: I'm looking at posts with information, not cars.

Comment: @VLAZ then you need to think of something else to eliminate the -ve number.

Comment: I do not need to do that, no.

Comment: Thanks. I'll not be doing that, either. I'm here to discuss your suggestion. Which I find dreadfully underthought. What *you* have to do is substantiate it. Instead of trying to get people who point out its flaws go away.

Comment: How about posts that have *both* DV and UV (i.e. controversial posts)?

Comment: Your progress bar idea will not solve your original problem of negativity though... High negative score(progress bar) may be perceived as bad. The moment you show any magnitude for poor score, it may be taken poorly.

Comment: Related (OP's previous question): [Downvote should not be negative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389790/2821954)

Comment: I still don't see what the benefit is. You just said "It's bad, change it this way" not why it's bad. Or how the change improves things. Initially you proposed showing nonsense numbers. Which you didn't explain how it helped. And then removed. Then you just had the asymmetric hiding of only downvoted items. Which I pointed out doesn't make sense. Now you have some sort of system which is...basically just the score. It can go positive or negative. Maybe not as granular but I really don't see how it's functionally different and how it fulfils your stated goal to "promote positivity".

Comment: I don't agree with this proposal because the trigger is all wrong, no we do not need to promote positivity. We promote usefulness. The current system does that just fine.

Comment: You could add 2,000,000 to all votes, so avoiding the negativity, and then new users who get downvoted don't need to be held at 2,000,001 - their rep. could go down without...'negativity'.

Comment: Proposals about changing the downvote system have been [asked and answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-it-required-to-provide-comments-feedback-for-downvotes-and-why-are-pr) many times. This proposal is incorrect for many of the reasons listed in the linked post.

Comment: @Gimby yeah. i forgot that emotion is irrelevant in coding. thanks for reminding me.

Comment: Emotion is not irrelevant - it's a big drag on progress, especially when testing/debugging.  Compilers/linkers/hardware have no emotion and, unless you focus on facts and results only, you will find it very difficult to persuade the soulless silicon to satisfy your specs:(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's say there are three answers to a question. One is -1, and the two are -20. With your original proposal they would all say downvoted, but there's one of those answers I might give a shot to on the grounds that that one downvote could have been wrong, and the others I certainly ought to skip over.

We then have a progress bar suggestion, but that also suffers from granularity and comparability problems. It seems much more difficult to tell at a glance which is the best answer.

How do I know the voting breakdown? There is a difference between a post that's had 10 upvotes and 10 downvotes, (particularly here on Meta) as compared to a post that's not been voted on at all. Perhaps the first post was wrong and has been corrected, but the second has simply not been tried at all by anyone.

Voting is not about positivity or negativity at all; it’s about content rating. Is the answer useful, or not, or actively harmful. That's what we need to know here in as a simple and obvious a way as possible. We need to be able to compare answers and try the best one first without squinting at a set of progress bars to try to figure it out.